# two ways of putting variables in a Hash

Tags: javascript

I was reading this code, and I was hoping someone could explain it.
I'm still a little new to JS and I believe this is saying the following:
When the website is submitted the content of the website which includes: the input tags, textareas, and the button get placed into a hash. My confusion is where does it get the properties 'id' and 'value' from..is it the ids and the values that are given to the content within the #siteform?

```
function submitSite() {
    var formHash = new Hash();
    $$('#siteForm input, #siteForm textarea, #siteForm input[type=submit]').each(function(el) {
        var key = el.getProperty('id');
        var value = el.getProperty('value').trim();
        formHash.set(key, value);
    });
    processManager.setOptions({
        data : {
            'encFormData' : JSON.encode(formHash)
        }
    }).send();
}
```

If that is the case what is the difference of placing the input of the user into variable that then get placed into a hash? See the following example:

```
   function submitSite(){
    var formHash = new Hash();
    formHash.dtDate = $('itemDate').value;
processManager.setOptions({
        data : {
            'encFormData' : JSON.encode(formHash)
        }
    }).send();
 }
```

Comment: `id` and `value` come from the HTML `<input id="xxx" value="yyy">`

Comment: `getProperty` is not a standard JavaScript function. It's coming from whatever library provides the `$$` function.

Comment: It looks like this code is using the MooTools library.

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to mention that. Yes I am using Mootools. Okay so essentially my explanation was somewhat right? The type=submit is the submit button right?

Comment: Yes. There's no really need to list that explicitly in the selector, since `#siteForm input` will match all `<input>` fields, which includes the `type=submit` button.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I appreciate the help